# Integer variable not incrementing

Tags: android, string

Is there something wrong with my code? I don't understand why its not working properly. I want to increment the value if the string from my edit text is the same as another string, but, somehow, the integer is not increamenting. Here is my code

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int score ;
    EditText q1;
    EditText q2;
    EditText q3;
    EditText q4;
    String ans1, ans2, ans3, ans1a,ans1b,ans1c;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        q1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer1);
        q2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer2);
        q3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer3);
        q4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EtScore);
        score = 0;
    }


    public void Calculate(View v){
        ans1=q1.getText().toString();
        ans2 = q2.getText().toString();
        ans3 = q3.getText().toString();

        if(ans1.equalsIgnoreCase("Obama")){ 
            score = score + 1;
        }

        if(ans2.equalsIgnoreCase("Naira")){

            score = score + 1;
        } 

        if(ans3.equalsIgnoreCase("Illinois")){

            score = score + 1;
        }


        q4.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess calculate is called by a button in your layout, isn't it?

Comment: yes i am calling calcutethrough onClick

Comment: have you tried to force redraw of the layout? (quick check, change the position of your mobile to landscape and check if score is properly updated)

Comment: Are you sure your Calculate(View v) method is getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainActivity.java

```js
package com.example.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 int score;
 EditText q1;
 EditText q2;
 EditText q3;
 EditText q4;
 String ans1, ans2, ans3, ans1a, ans1b, ans1c;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  q1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer1);
  q2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer2);
  q3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
  q4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
  score = 0;
 }



 public void Calculate(View v) {
  ans1 = q1.getText().toString();
  ans2 = q2.getText().toString();
  ans3 = q3.getText().toString();

  if (ans1.equalsIgnoreCase("Obama")) {
   score = score + 1;
  }

  if (ans2.equalsIgnoreCase("Naira")) {

   score = score + 1;
  }

  if (ans3.equalsIgnoreCase("Illinois")) {

   score = score + 1;
  }

  q4.setText(String.valueOf(score));
 }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etAnswer1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etAnswer2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Calculate"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The above code produce [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgSYJ.jpg)

Comment: works, can you please tell me what i did wrong in my code or how you fixed it, cos our codes are literally the same thing

Comment: I think your calculate method is not getting called. Is your button like this
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Calculate"
        android:text="Button" />

Answer (score 0):

chech this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html and set all Edit text with `afterTextChanged(),beforeTextChanged(), onTextChanged().`

```
    q1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             //call method where you are chceking
             isMatch(s);
      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
      }

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      }
   });


   private void isMatch(String s){
    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Obama")){ 
        score = score + 1;
    }

    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Naira")){

        score = score + 1;
    } 

    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Illinois")){

        score = score + 1;
    }


    q4.setText(String.valueOf(score));

   }
```

Comment: please @5er can you explain a little more, i have never used text watcher before

Comment: @AigbomianVII I wrote you an example above. Maybe the calling of isMatch(s) will be needed to move inside `beforeTextChanged()` or `onTextChanged()`

Comment: @AigbomianVII  you have to add listeners .addTextChangedListener to all q1 q2 q3

Comment: still not working doesn't even display default value of score anymore

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is the issue,

Firstly I am assuming you want to calculate "score" on the button click event. However no where is there a onClick event callback. In this case the "score" will be tabulated only when the activity is created.

So here is what I would do (assuming your XML is defined correctly),

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayoutHere, container,false);
         q1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer1);
         q2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer2);
         q3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer3);
         q4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EtScore);
        rootview.findViewById(R.id.yourButtonHere).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Calculate();

        }
    });

    return rootview;
}   



public void Calculate() {
        ans1 = q1.getText().toString();
        ans2 = q2.getText().toString();
        ans3 = q3.getText().toString();

        if (ans1.equalsIgnoreCase("Obama")) {
            score = score + 1;
        }

        if (ans2.equalsIgnoreCase("Naira")) {

            score = score + 1;
        }

        if (ans3.equalsIgnoreCase("Illinois")) {

            score = score + 1;
        }

        q4.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }
```